# On mouse hover, change picture in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have an image in my HTML code, and I want to make it so that when my mouse is hovering over the image, it will change to the other image, and when the mouse is **not** hovering over the image, it switches back to the default. How do I program this in a `<script>` tag?

Comment: Please post your existing code and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No `<script>` tag necessary. Use [`onmouseover`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp) and [`onmouseout`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseout.asp) to change the image source.

`onmouseover` will execute an action when your **mouse goes over the image**. In this case, we use `this.src` to set the image src to another image.

`onmouseout` will execute an action when your **mouse goes out of the image**. In this case, we use `this.src` again to set the image to the default image.

```html
<img title="Hello" src="https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2017/09/12/11/naturo-monkey-selfie.jpg?w968h681" onmouseover="this.src='https://www.ctvnews.ca/polopoly_fs/1.4037876!/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/landscape_1020/image.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2017/09/12/11/naturo-monkey-selfie.jpg?w968h681'" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use css for this like:

```
.react {

  background: url('../img/React_Monoo.png');
}

.react:hover {
  background: url('../img/React_Colored.png');
}
```

here react is a class name

Answer (score 0):

```
var image = document.getElementById("image");

//Now, we need to add an Event Listener to listen when the image gets mouse over.

image.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
  image.src = "path/to/newimage"
})
image.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
    image.src = "path/to/otherimage"
  })
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the on mouse out for this.
here is my Work on it.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
 <script>

 function setnewimage() {
 document.getElementById("img2").src = "myquiz1.png";
 }
 function setnewimage1() {
 document.getElementById("img2").src = "myquiz2.png";
 }
 function setnewimage2() {
 document.getElementById("img2").src = "myquiz3.png";
 }
 function setnewimage3() {
 document.getElementById("img2").src = "pic33.png";
 }
 function setoldimage() {
 document.getElementById("img2").src = "myquiz1.png";
 }
 </script>
 <div>
 <img id="img2" src="" width="300">
 <br>
 <img id="img1" src="myquiz1.PNG" onmouseover="setnewimage()"
width="300" onmouseout="setoldimage()">
 <img id="img66" src="myquiz2.PNG" onmouseover="setnewimage1()"
width="300" height="200" onmouseout="setoldimage()">
 <img id="img87" src="myquiz3.PNG" onmouseover="setnewimage2()"
width="300" height="200" onmouseout="setoldimage()">
 <img id="img80" src="pic33.PNG" onmouseover="setnewimage3()"
width="300" height="200" onmouseout="setoldimage()">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```